# Mailjet API v3 update

Tags: java, api, mailjet

I have a serious issue regarding the REST API of Mailjet as used with the [recommended v3 library](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-java#42-update-of-resource-instance).

When I try to UPDATE I am able to do so for the first time without errors, but when I try to do so again, I got `NullPointerException`. In spite of that, it does update the stat in the Mailjet Server part.

Also the HTTP Response I get is `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

**Code used:**

```
thisUser=cl.createCall(User.Update).identifiedBy(UserProperty.ID, **myUniqueID**).property(UserProperty.USERNAME, propertyValue).execute();
```

Any thoughts would be more than welcome.

Ok after the comment, here is the function:

```
         @Path("/userUpdate/{propertyName}/{propertyValue}")
     @GET
     public Response userUpdate(@PathParam("propertyName") String propertyName, @PathParam("propertyValue") String propertyValue) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
         MailJetApiClient cl=null;
         User thisUser=null;
         Response resp=null;

         StringEntity stringEntity = null;

        try {
            cl = MailjetUsersRest.createClient();
        } catch (MailJetClientConfigurationException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            thisUser=cl.createCall(User.Get).identifiedBy(UserProperty.ID, ___MY_UNIQUE_ID___).execute();
        } catch (MailJetApiCallException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        String email = thisUser.getEmail();
        String lastip = thisUser.getLastIp();
        Date lastlogin = thisUser.getLastLoginAt();
        String local = thisUser.getLocale();
        String timezone = thisUser.getTimezone();
        Date warned = thisUser.getWarnedRatelimitAt();          

         try {

            cl = MailjetUsersRest.createClient();

            switch(propertyName){

            case "Username":

                thisUser=cl.createCall(User.Update).identifiedBy(UserProperty.ID, ___MY_UNIQUE_ID___).property(UserProperty.USERNAME, propertyValue).execute();

                resp = Response.status(200).entity(thisUser).build();

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid propertyName.");
                break;
            }

        } catch (MailJetClientConfigurationException | MailJetApiCallException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            return resp;
     }
```

Comment: Hi @ODstuck. Could you put the whole code you used? Don't forget to **sanitise it** from every personal info / API keys and, at best, **use the code formatting available on SO** (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for using Mailjet!

After some testing, I was unable to reproduce your issue. You will find below the code I used.

**However** I strongly suggest that you open a ticket with our support [here](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket).

### A working code

*Please note that it is unnecessary and considered bad practice to rebuild the client before each call.*

```
// Build a Mailjet client config
MailJetClientConfiguration config;

config = new MailJetClientConfiguration()
                .setBaseUrl("https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/")
                .setDefaultApiKey(System.getenv("MJ_PROD_PUBLIC"))
                .setDefaultSecretKey(System.getenv("MJ_PROD_PRIVATE"));

// Build a Mailjet client
MailJetApiClient client = config.buildClient();

// Your code (adapted to my environment, ie no 'Response' object 
// and no client factory.)
User thisUser = null;

try
{
    // Note that the 'L' in the 'identifiedBy' value fi is necessary
    thisUser = client
                .createCall(User.Get)
                .identifiedBy(UserProperty.ID, /*Our user's ID*/L)
                .execute();
}
catch (MailJetApiCallException e2)
{
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

String email = thisUser.getEmail();
String lastip = thisUser.getLastIp();
Date lastlogin = thisUser.getLastLoginAt();
String local = thisUser.getLocale();
String timezone = thisUser.getTimezone();
Date warned = thisUser.getWarnedRatelimitAt();

try
{
    thisUser = client
                .createCall(User.Update)
                .identifiedBy(UserProperty.ID, /*Our user's ID*/L)
                .property(UserProperty.USERNAME, "DevRel Team Mailjet")
                .execute();

}
catch (MailJetApiCallException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Copy pasting the last bit (the update process) so that the update call is executed twice (without the same new username, of course) doesn't throw any error and certainly not a `NullPointerException` or a 500 HTTP error code.
And the username is changed accordingly.

So yeah, as written above, please contact our support [here](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket). This will allow us to better help you.

If this answer satisfies you, don't forget to accept & upvote it so that others going through similar issues can know this helped :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Mr. Gormador. I have been away these last 7 days. It only makes sense that your statement of bad practice to rebuild the client is the issue. I still get a 500 http error code, but the update is done. Maybe its on my side. As i progress i will know more. Thank you again for the time and consideration, Remaining yours, OD

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't hesitate to post a new question here or over on our [github repository for the Java wrapper](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-java/issues) should you encounter another issue.
Our support is also available through [here](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket)! :-)